# How to Access "Checkpoint Key" Property in Data Flow Activity Settings in Azure Synapse Analytics and Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

**Context**
I am currently using Azure Synapse Analytics to extract change feed data from CosmosDB. My setup involves:

- CosmosDB configured with Synapse Link.
- A parameterized query run against the analytical store using an inline dataset within a data flow.
- This data flow is part of a parameterized pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics.

**Issue:**
I need to override the checkpoint key in the pipeline. However, I am encountering a challenge:

- In the settings tab of the data flow activity within the pipeline, I am unable to locate the option to override the checkpoint key as [indicated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-data-flow-activity#create-a-data-flow-activity-with-ui).

**Question:**
What are the prerequisites or specific conditions that trigger the visibility of the "Checkpoint Key" property in the settings tab of a data flow activity in both Azure Synapse Analytics and Azure Data Factory?

**Attempts to Resolve:**
I have recreated the pipelines and dataflows in Data Factory in order to determine if it was an issue with my Synapse configuration with no success. The issue exists in both Synapse and ADF.

**Expected Outcome:**
I am looking to understand how to access or enable the "Checkpoint Key" property in the data flow activity settings to override it in my pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Checkpoint Key** shows only when you enable **Change data capture** in the source configuration of a dataflow activity. I have checked with **DelimitedText** as a source, and it was working fine.

However, when I selected the source as **CosmosDb**, by default **Change data capture** was enabled, but I still faced the same issue: the **Checkpoint Key** was not showing.

[image]

The **Checkpoint Key** will be displayed according to the dataset selected.

So, I figured out that I first needed to enable **Change data capture** by selecting **DelimitedText** as the input type in **Source settings**.

[image]

and

[image]

Then, you will get the **Checkpoint Key**.

[image]

After that, you can change the source data to **CosmosDb** and will be able to **Override**.

[image]

Comment: That does it. It feels like a bug related to the fact when using the analytical store, you are not explicitly checking the "Change Data Capture" checkbox. When checking this with delimited text, it modifies the referencing pipelines of the data flow, to add the property to the underlying json. Since this it not explicitly clicked, I am guessing the triggered action to update the pipelines is never fired.